# Execute correctly a bash command that have interactive input

Tags: bash

I try to execute from bash a command and retrieve stdout, stderr and exit code.
So far so good, there is plenty way.

The problem begin when that the program have an interactive input.

More precisly, I execute "git commit" (without -m) and "GNU nano" is executed in order to put a commit message.

If I use simply :

```
git commit
```

or

```
exec git commit
```

I can see the prompt, but I can't get stdout/stderr.

If I use

```
output=`git commit 2>&1`
```

or

```
output=$(git commit 2>&1)
```

I can retrieve stdout/stderr, but I can't see the prompt.
I can still do ctrl+X to abort the git commit.

My first attempt was by function call and my script end up hanging on a blank screen and ctrl+x / ctrl+c doesn't work.

```
function Execute()
{
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error : function 'Execute' called without argument."
        exit 3
    fi


    local msg=$("$@ 2>&1")
    local error=$?
    if [[ $error -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error : '"$(printf '%q ' "$@")"' return '$error' error code."
        echo "$1 message :"
        echo "$msg"
        echo
        exit 1
    fi
}

Execute git commit
```

I begin to ran out of idea/knowledge. Is what I want to do impossible ? Or is there a way that I don't know ?

Comment: You might want to create the commit message *first*, the use `git commit -F` to create the commit non-interactively from the prepared file.

Comment: Try not doing `2&1` as the prompt is almost certainly going to stderr and then you're capturing it along with the eventual stdout.

Comment: @chepner I search a general solution. I can indeed force to have a commit message, but I prefer to have more choice.

Comment: @EdMorton I want to retrieve stdout and stderr. How can I retrieve both of them without 2 > &1 ?

Comment: That's not true though - you don't want to capture stdout and stderr because the prompt is coming to stderr (I'm guessing) and you're saying you don't want to capture it. It sounds like you want to capture some parts of stderr in a variable along with stdout but other parts you want to separate from stdout and print to the screen instead - idk how you'll pull that off!

Comment: @EdMorton My basic need is what is stated in my first line : "execute [...] a command and retrieve stdout, stderr and exit code". Il you have a way to execute something, and retrieve stdout in a variable and strderr in another variable, i'm ready to hear that. But I found out that sometime it's more useful to have stderr redirected on stdout because you can see the evolution of the error. I'm not sure if I'm clear.

Comment: That's not your basic need though as that would be easy and it's what your code already does, Your basic need is to split stderr into a prompt that goes immediately to the screen and an error message that, if it occurs, gets saved in a variable for printing later.

Comment: @EdMorton Okay, so I think now why I don't see the interactive gnu : it's because stdout is captured in case of backquote or $(...). And now, I don't see how I will do it, because if I don't capture stdout, it will be printed (and I don't want to) and If I capture it in order to it to not be printed, I will not see the interactive prompt ... damn. Look like I will have to force "-m" option and be careful.

Comment: Can you set your editor to be a GUI so that it won't mess with your stdout/err streams? `export GIT_EDITOR=gvim` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this which processes every line output to stdout or stderr and redirects based on content:

```
#!/bin/env bash

foo() {
    printf 'prompt: whos on first?\n' >&2
    printf 'error: uh-oh\n' >&2
}

var=$(foo 2>&1 | awk '{print | "cat>&"(/prompt/ ? 2 : 1)}' )
echo "var=$var"

$ ./tst.sh
prompt: whos on first?
var=error: uh-oh
```

or this which just processes stderr:

```
#!/bin/env bash

foo() {
    printf 'prompt: whos on first?\n' >&2
    printf 'error: uh-oh\n' >&2
}

var=$(foo 2> >(awk '{print | "cat>&"(/prompt/ ? 2 : 1)}') )
echo "var=$var"

$ ./tst.sh
prompt: whos on first?
var=error: uh-oh
```

The awk command splits it's input to stderr or stdout based on content and only stdout is saved in the variable `var`. I don't know if your prompt is coming to stderr or stdout or where you really want it go go but massage to suit wrt what you want to go to stdout vs stderr and what you want to capture in the variable vs see printed to the screen. You just need to have something in the prompt to recognize as such so you can separate the prompt from the rest of the stdout and stderr and print the prompt to stderr while everything else gets redirected to stdout.

Alternatively here's a version that prints the first line (regardless of content) to stderr for display and everything else to stdout for capture:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

foo() {
    printf 'prompt: whos on first?\n' >&2
    printf 'error: uh-oh\n' >&2
}

var=$(foo 2>&1 | awk '{print | "cat>&"(NR>1 ? 1 : 2)}' )
echo "var=$var"

$ ./tst.sh
prompt: whos on first?
var=error: uh-oh
```